# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyimagesearch (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyimagesearch

Tags: python, installation

**pip install pyimagesearch**

When I run the above command in anaconda prompt with administrator rights, I am getting following error. I have already installed cv2.

> Collecting pyimagesearch
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyimagesearch (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pyimagesearch

`Cv2  Version -- 4.1.0`

Please suggest.

Comment: `pyimagesearch` doesn't exist on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pyimagesearch). Why do you think you need it? It seems like no package with that name exists, I also briefly checked Github in case it's a project you need to install manually. Can you doublecheck that you spelled it correctly and that it is the package you need to install?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you might have taken code form **https://www.pyimagesearch.com**.
At the end of his tutorials he provides a link for zip codes. You have to download the zip file. This zip file has this module. ***pyimagesearch*** . If you can't find any, send be the tutorial link, i will find that for you.

At the end of the page it has a box like image, type your email there.[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYh8K.png)